# On maximizing the matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given a positive $M\times M$ matrix $A$, let $f(A,X) = \det(X^H A X)$ where $X$ is a $M\times L$ matrix with $L \le M$ and each column of $X$ is a unit vector. In order to maximize $f(A,X)$, it is clear that $X$ should be composed of $L$ eigenvectors of $A$ with its largest eigenvalues. But what if there are some limitations on $X$, say some elements of $X$ have to be zeros? Given such kind of patterns of $X$, e.g., $X = \text{Diag}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_L)$ and $x_i$ are vectors, is there still possible to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "each column of X is uniformed" ?

Comment: The diagonal of $X^H X$ is all 1s.

Comment: In more standard terminology, this condition means that each column is a unit vector (dot product with itself is one). I've edited the text to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a (rectangular) diagonal matrix and each column of $X$ is a unit vector, those diagonal elements must have unit moduli. In turn, $\det(X^HAX)$ is always equal to the determinant of the leading principal $L\times L$ submatrix of $A$, regardless of $X$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer of high value. I just want to make it clear one more thing. If the pattern of $X$ is given, such that some elements are always zeros, is there a way to get the optimal $X$? E.g., the simple way of getting the maximum is by setting the corresponding $k-th$ elements of that column of a $X$ to be one. But if that element has to be zero, can we still get the optimum? To be more specific, let $X$ be of the following pattern, only $X(2i-1:2i, i)\ne 0$ and the rest part of $X$ is 0, is it still feasible (in this case, $M =2L$)? Thank you again.

Comment: @Distance No idea. Sorry.